# Other application except browser not able to connect to internet via proxy with authentification on android emulator

Tags: android

By setting the proxy ip address and port number,i can connect to internet through browser only via proxy authentification of username and password but other application not able to connect to the internet on android emulator.please help

Comment: Did you specify the username and password in the settings field?

Comment: yes i have specified username & password.But not working in android emulator

Answer (score -1):

That is part of how Android proxy works. you can try using this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en